# C# UWP stress testing: How to simulate a button press

Tags: c#, xaml, debugging, memory-management, uwp

When I repeatedly press a buttons in my UI, I see the memory usage increases without an apparent limit (starts at ~9MB and 2 minutes of pressing results in ~12MB).

I thought I had programmed things so that there were no loose ends within the button click event handler, so I'm very motivated to find out what happens after pressing this button many many times (stress test). I've tried two methods for automating the stress test:

Method 1 is that I run the code inside the event handler using a timer.

Method 2 looks like this:

```
//I think following using statements give access to controls automation within UWP
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Provider;

public MainPage()
{
    //Everything else I'm doing to set up the main page goes here

    buttonTestTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    buttonTestTimer.Tick += ButtonTestTimer_Tick;
    buttonTestTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
    buttonTestTimer.Start();
}

private void ButtonTestTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    var ap = new ButtonAutomationPeer(btn_Toggle);
    var ip = ap.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
    ip?.Invoke();
}
```

Neither method results in > ~10MB memory usage, even though they are performing the events much faster than when I manually press the button over and over.

So they do not seem to be an accurate way to simulate the manual button pressing.

Am I wrong to want to stress test automatically? How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to test for? You have apparently observed an increase in memory usage following user interaction, although it's unclear, what *"memory usage"* means to you. Do you have reason to believe, that this indicates some sort of issue?

Comment: Thank you for responding: I am trying to test to see how much memory the program will use after MANY manual button presses. Regarding "memory usage" I look in visual studio "Process Memory" in "Diagnostic Tools" tab and see the value. I thought program memory usage would go back to level prior to button click. Because that's not the case, and because memory usage only increases as I click the button, I want to see the limit. I am under the assumption that if memory usage increases per user interaction, then I will eventually have a problem.

Comment: Are you using a separate application to press the buttons, or is it built into the program you are testing?

Comment: Right now I'm trying to build it into the program to be tested. I don't think it matters to me if I build it into that program or if I can find another way to do it.